How to product_tag active in Product Filters list Woocommerce
In my bookstore, I use a GET request with the product_tag parameter to filter by tags. How can I display the tag name in the Active Filter Widget? I found a hook in class-wc-widget-layered-nav-filters.php but I can't use it properly.
do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_layered_nav_filters_start', $args, $instance );
How can I edit the array of active filters in PHP to add filters from the product_tag parameter?
